# How to run an awk commands in Windows?

Tags: windows, awk

I have downloaded gawk from [*here*](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), but I can't seem to figure out how to use it. I am simply trying to run a command, not to write one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to avoid including the full path to awk, you need to update your PATH variable to include the path to the directory where awk is located, then you can just type

```
awk
```

to run your programs.

Go to Control Panel->System->Advanced and set your PATH environment variable to include "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" at the end (separated by a semi-colon) from previous entry.
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Quoting is an issue if you're running awk from the command line.  You'll sometimes need to use `\`, e.g. to quote `"`, but most of the time you'll use `^`:

```
w:\srv>dir | grep ".txt" | awk "{ printf(\"echo %s@%s ^> %s.tstamp^\n\", $1, $2, $4); }"
echo 2014-09-07@22:21 > requirements-dev.txt.tstamp
echo 2014-11-28@18:14 > syncspec.txt.tstamp
```

Answer (score 6):

You can download and run the setup file. This should install your `AWK` in "`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`". You can run the `awk` or `gawk` command from the `bin` folder or add the  folder ``C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`to your`PATH`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can install awk:
`choco install awk`

Then you can use:
`awk`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I do like mark instruction but little differently.
I've added `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\` to the Path variable,
and try to run it with type awk using cmd.

Hope it works.

Comment: i have installed awk and gwak on my pc. once you type awk after the installation, it should work. for the first time, im using path taht refers where awk.exe was stored. and execute some command.

Answer (score 1):

Go to command windows (cmd) then type:

```
"c:\Progam Files(x86)\GnuWin32\bin\awk"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://scoop.sh/

With Scoop, you can install the awk for your windows terminal.
Scoop automatically finds and installs the dependencies.

```
scoop install gawk
```

[awk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Uva.png)

[awk2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6skoL.png)

homepage: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/