# automatically get computer user for a directory

Tags: file-io, directory, finder

I made a password saving program that saves to a file in a specific directory

```
static String fly = "C:\\Users\\tomtom\\Documents\\AlternativePorjectDirectory\\accounts";

                          user--/\/\/\
                                ||||||
```

but everytime I give this softwar to someone I have to ask them for their user, rewrite the software then, export to usb and give it to them. automatically finding the computer user will make it so I can share this program with everyone.
what I want it to look like

```
static String fly = "C:\\Users\\"+C:User+"\\Documents\\AlternativePorjectDirectory\\accounts";
```

so that computer user= C:User

I am very new to programming so may have to be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to do that, and since the user folder isn't always C:\Users\, there's a better way.

%USERPROFILE% is an environment variable that will always be equal to the user folder, for example C:\Users\SomeGuy, or on an XP system, C:\Documents and Settings\SomeOtherGuy.

Just:

```
DWORD nSize = MAX_PATH;
CHAR* lpBuffer = new CHAR[nSize];
GetEnvironmentVariableA("USERPROFILE",lpBuffer,nSize);
static String fly = lpBuffer+"\\Documents\\AlternativePorjectDirectory\\accounts";
```

Comment: thanks! do I have to make lpBuffer and nSize variables

Comment: Yes you do.  See my edit above, I changed a bit of code.
Make sure to user GetEnvironmentVariableA to force to ASCII.

The code above should work for whatever you need, but for a deeper explanation, [read the page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: sorry but I cant get it to work I am not an experienced programmer like you could you send me an example of how I would be used in a finished code

Comment: Try adding `#include <windows.h>` to the top of your code (.cpp file) or into your header (.h) file.

Comment: still I cant get it to work idk if im doing it right like I really need an example on a very short completed code

Comment: Can you please post the compile errors that you're getting?

Comment: idk how sorry can you tell me what I need to declare and stuff

Answer (score -1):

If you can use scripting, the answer will be:

```
awk -F '//' '{print $2}'
```

Here is a post outlining how to get awk:
[How to run an awk commands in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows)

Comment: im using java eclipse