# How to launch a shell script make with Linux on Windows

Tags: linux, r, shell, awk

I have a shell script make with Linux with this code:

```
 #!/bin/sh

    awk '{ print $3,$2,$4,$1}' df_real_credit_network_B0.00_BC0.00_l33.33_day1 > credit_adj
    awk '{ print $3,$2,$5,$1}' df_real_interbank_network_B0.00_BC0.00_l33.33_day1 > interbank_adj
```

The script creates two objects: "credit_adj" and "interbank_adj", necessary for others scripts for the software `R`. Obliviously Windows don't recognize the script, so I try to modify the extension ".sh" with ".bat" and I deleted the string `"#!/bin/sh"` from the script.
In this way the two objects are created but are empty, because windows don't recognize the instruction `awk`.
How can I create the two objects correctly?

Thanks

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly run a Unix shell script in windows, One way to run unix/Linux shell script in windows is , install cygwin in windows and run script inside cygwin

Comment: I'm trying to instal cygwin on my pc, but doesn't work...I've downloaded the installer from [link](https://www.cygwin.com/) but don't start..