# PowerCenter - Extract Date from source filename

Tags: bash, awk, etl, informatica-powercenter

I want to extract the date of an empty file , example :

**Orders_05012015.txt**

This, to occupy it as a variable to query the database.

```
select * from orders Where date = $$Date_order (05012015)
```

I try to do this task by command , but I only get it via examples of AWK and I'm in windows

Example via awk:

```
SET CompletePath=\\192.168.20.175\infa_shared\SrcFiles\CRED20102009.csv
SET JustFileName=`basename $CompletePath`
echo $JustFileName|awk -F"." '{print $1}'|awk '{print substr($1,length($1)-7, length($1))}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell in Windows

```
$a=[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("\\192.168.20.175\infa_shared\SrcFiles\CRED20102009.csv")
$a.substring($a.length-8,8)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are awk implementations for Windows:

[Gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)
[Microsoft's answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/how-to-run-grep-and-awk-on-windows/73fb9fd6-92f3-4b5f-baf4-38c60c0ca397?auth=1)
[From StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows)