# Delete Error rows and columns with wrong dtype at same time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, memory, dataframe

I have a large dataset with 16 columns and about 1 billion rows.

In this dataset I am facing two major problems

1. I am having error rows as in the count of columns for some rows is `more or less` than 16 columns

I am using `error_rows=False`That is skipping the rows but I am performing some 30 operations and everytime that is taking too much of time.

2. One of the columns is `DateTime` in human readable format. While performing one of the operations of converting human readable to `Unix` format. The `dtype` is not readable mostly because the `error_rows`

That is giving me error & warning about `dtype` or insert `low_memory=False`

If I am inserting the `dtype` then next error and warning is shifting to another column.

Code:

```
 for i in input_files:
        Tmp_Table = pd.DataFrame()
        address = direc + i
        df = pd.read_csv(address,sep=',',error_bad_lines=False)
```

Column `3` out of `16` columns is `datetime` and seems the column have mixed `dtype` may be due to error rows. To avoid that I used `low_memory=False` and that is also giving me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FirstTable.py", line 20, in <module>
    Tmp_Table['Datetime'] = df['Tweeted Datetime'].apply(lambda x: UnixFormat(str(x)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1569, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66440)
  File "FirstTable.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    Tmp_Table['Datetime'] = df['Tweeted Datetime'].apply(lambda x: UnixFormat(str(x)))
  File "/home/lakshmi/Desktop/Twitter_Code_Ubuntu/Functions.py", line 41, in UnixFormat
    unixtime = previous
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'previous' referenced before assignment
```

Hence I am trying to find a simple and quick way to Delete those error rows once for all from the dataset so that my next operations are not taking so much .

Any one can suggest me the best way to do so.. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you were saying something about Unix format, I assume that you are on a unix system.
If so, you can use `awk` to preprocess your data.

If your delimiter is tabs:

```
awk 'NF==16{print}{}' data > data_edit
```

If your delimiter is a comma:

```
awk -F',' 'NF==16{print}{}' data > data_edit
```

awk will check for the number of columns, and will only filter out those equal to 16. After that, just store these into data_edit

Now you should be left with a dataset containing 16 columns, and hopefully this will solve most of your issues.

If you want to check the number of columns in your file:

```
awk -F',' '{print NF}' data | sort | uniq -c
```

this will print out two columns: number of occurences - number of columns

Comment: Yes i think i am looking for something like that only.. This is a csv file so can i pass the csv file name in place of data?  And put output csv file name for data_edit?

Comment: yes correct! awk can handle all plain text files. To be clear: I know that you posted this with pandas tags, but my experience with DataFrames and changing number of columns is not that fruitful, that's why I'm suggesting you this solution.

Comment: I am open to every kind of solution..  I used pandas to have headers in case needed

Comment: THe problem might have solved but the problem is I have lost huge number of rows and the file size reduced from 1gb to 80 mb but that should not be the case.

Comment: What is the column delimiter in your file? Is there a pattern in the missing columns, e.a. The last one is always missing.

Comment: It is csv file and there is no pattern actually that is wat main problem is..  There are some row element missing or shift in placing of element..

Comment: and what is the column delimiter? tabs, commas, semicolumn ... ?

Comment: Comma is the delimiter

Comment: Thank you..  I Will check and let you know

Comment: Sir in case i want to run the cleaning on windows terminal or anaconda prompt how should i write the command?

Comment: @SitzBlogz check this link for awk on windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows