# execute awk scripts in windows machine

Tags: awk, gawk

How to execute .awk script (currently running on linux) within windows environment ?

Steps done till date:
Installed GAWK-3.1.6-1 on my windows system

Please provide some advice, how to execute the .awk file from windows

Comment: check if this url helps you once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh, thank for your immediate response on this. the situation is i have some .awk scripts in a file which is doing some data manipulation and it is running currently on Linux system. i want to execute the same script in Windows 2012 server either from  (.bat/powershell for automate) to call my .awk. please advice with some steps

Comment: `awk -f scriptfile inputfile`.

Comment: btw that is an **extremely** old version of gawk you have and it's missing a ton of bug fixes and extremely useful newer functionality. It's literally about 5 years out of date, we're now on gawk 4.1.4. Get a new one. Also - just get cygwin and run gawk from that instead of having to fight with Windows nightmarish quoting rules.