# awk append with /32 not working in MS Windows

Tags: windows, awk, cmd

I am trying to append /32 to public IP that is in a file using awk

ip.txt has IP address `4.14.XX.XXX`

the issue is with the command in script file

```
awk "{print $0 "/32"}" < ip.txt
```

result=`0.129375`

if I remove `/` than the result is `4.14.XX.XXX32`

I want `4.14.XX.XXX/32.`

The complete bat file

```
curl v4.ifconfig.co > ip.txt
awk "{ print $0 "/32" }" < ip.txt > ipnew.txt
@REM set stuff=type ipnew.txt
for /f %%i in ('type ipnew.txt') do set stuff=%%i
echo %stuff%
```

====================

awk -f changeipaddress.bat

error

```
awk: changeipaddress.bat:1: curl v4.ifconfig.co > ip.txt
awk: changeipaddress.bat:1:        ^ syntax error
awk: changeipaddress.bat:1: curl v4.ifconfig.co > ip.txt
awk: changeipaddress.bat:1:                         ^ syntax error
awk: changeipaddress.bat:2: awk "{ print $0 "/32" }" < ip.txt > ipnew.txt
awk: changeipaddress.bat:2:                              ^ syntax error
awk: changeipaddress.bat:2: awk "{ print $0 "/32" }" < ip.txt > ipnew.txt
awk: changeipaddress.bat:2:                                          ^ syntax error
awk: changeipaddress.bat:3: @REM set stuff=type ipnew.txt
awk: changeipaddress.bat:3: ^ invalid char '@' in expression
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong?

Regards,
TJ.

Comment: use single quotes to enclose the script... `awk '{print $0 "/32"}'` ... see [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: on noticing `window` in title... may be you can't use single quotes.. please add appropriate tag to get better help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an awk commands in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows)

Comment: Answer in there about how to escape quotes and the issues like that you can run into when running awk for windows.

Comment: @EdMorton from CMD prompt in MS

Comment: @Sundeep i am not understanding about tag to add. In the question, I have added double quote and that is why its giving result but wrong value. My issue is when using backward slash and how to solve it.

Comment: @EdMorton actually my script file have some more command line argument like curl and set  commands. so it failing while coming to awk.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried running as suggested but getting systax error example awk: changeipaddress.bat:1: curl v4.ifconfig.co > ip.txt

Comment: @EdMorton.. Just updated the thread. Hopefully that give more details

Comment: @EdMorton thank you!! it's working finally. Learned new lesson and how to use the forum. Thank you again for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `foo.awk` with content `{ print $0 "/32" }` (i.e. the awk script) then change line 2 of your bat file from `awk "{ print $0 "/32" }" < ip.txt > ipnew.txt` to `awk -f foo.awk < ip.txt > ipnew.txt`. Now run your bat file however you normally do.