# Extract a specific column from the windows command prompt output using Ansible

Tags: windows, awk, ansible

I wanted to get the 3rd and 5th column output. I used the below command in  my playbook.

`win_shell: dir | awk '{print $3,$5}'`

But I get output as below.

```
        "awk : The term 'awk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the ",
        "spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.",]
```

When I execute the command via the windows prompt I get the expected output. Please help.

Comment: the win_shell module uses powershell as default shell. Since cmd is working you can use win_command. Also it would be worth to check the same execution via power shell

Comment: when using win_command i still get error as "Failed to process input: The parameter 'awk' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057)."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform you column extraction in Ansible rather than using `awk`.  For example, assuming you've registered the output of your `win_shell` task in a variable called `result`, you could do this:

```
- debug:
    var: item.split()|json_query('[[2], [4]]')
  loop: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

This would display the 3rd and 5th column (arrays are zero-indexed) from each line of output.  Maybe you want to put this in a list instead of just displaying it:

```
- set_fact:
    data: "{{ data|default([]) + [item.split()|json_query('[[2], [4]]')] }}"
  loop: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```