# Read only specific columns of SPSS .sav files into R

Tags: r, windows, import, spss

I'm importing some SPSS .sav files into R.

They are huge, thousands of rows, thousands of variables. But I only need 3 or 4 key variables from the data.

Is there any way to let an import function (currently using read_sav() from the "haven" package) what variables these are to cut down on upload time?

Cheers

Comment: You could try [`awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222121/372935), it appears to be also available for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21927944/6574038).

Comment: @jay.sf - `.sav` files are a proprietary format.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I don't understand the connection to my comment. Moreover, I have .sav that look quite comma separated and thus awk applicable.

Comment: @jay.sf They are not text data, they are a proprietary binary format.  `haven` uses the `ReadStat` C library to decode them.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks very much for clarification. In this case I would prefer the use of [`ReadStat`](https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat) over haven.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `col_select` argument of `haven::read_sav` function

```
library(haven)
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".sav")
write_sav(mtcars, tmp)

all_data <- read_sav(tmp)
someCol_data <- read_sav(tmp, col_select = c("hp", "mpg"))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much faster. I wonder if it is just loading up all the the data and then deleting what I'm not asking for, rather than specifically getting just the data I'm after. Thanks anyway.